# Iterating through a python sqlite db using data as a timer variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an sqlite database with four columns: cycle_no, step, color, duration. I would like to run the color for each step in the cycle for the duration indicated. For example, if the database contains this: toRun = [(1,1,red,2),(1,2,blue,4), (1,3,green,3) then red will light for two minutes, blue for 4 minutes and green for 3 minutes. I am using wx.Timer and the process starts on a button click.

```
def onRun(self, event):

    toRun = self.c.execute("SELECT * from cycles WHERE Cycle_No=1").fetchall()
    print toRun

    for row in toRun:
        #something here


    self.setTime()
    self.lightTimer.Start(10000)

def setTime(self):
    global timeOn
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeOn = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=dur) 
    print timeOn

def checkRunTime(self,event):
    global timeOn,
    if timeOn < datetime.datetime.now():
        print 'check time'
```

I'm not having any luck with the loop. Either all the colors go off at once or only the last color lights.
Thank you.

Comment: Please note that tables and queries have no guaranteed order unless you use ORDER BY.

Comment: Do you want to create all three timers at once? Or to change the timer when the previous step has expired?

Comment: I need a timer for each step? Can I put a loop in the checkRunTime function and once the duration from the first step is done, run the next step?

Comment: You get a message when the timer expires. In the message handler, start the next timer.

Comment: I'm still having trouble visualizing the code (self-taught newbie with no programming experience). Should I pull one record at a time, when that one completes loop back and pull the next?

Comment: You need to remember either the step number, so that you can retrieve the next one, or the entire list.